# Code a Web Analytics Tool

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-analytics

I am trying to capture click events in my existing Java/J2EE intranet  application.

The application has been in production and we are trying to add this feature.

In order to accomplish this; we've created a javascript function which sends the required data in the form of Ajax call to server and we've able to capture the required data.

However, in order to implement this, we had to manually add javascript calls via onclick events to places from where we wanted to capture data.

This includes radio , submit , menu clicks ,etc.
 Is this approach of adding onclick tags to respective controls correct or is there a smarter way to handle this?

We're a bit resistant to use a tool for this considering some compliance directives.

Sample onclick call:

```
onclick="footprint.trace('CLK_REGISTER_BTN');validateForm();"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).click(function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id); // gives the element's ID 
    alert(e.target.className); // gives the elements class(es)
  });

</script>
```

Above code resolved my query. I was able to get all click events on page which are super set of button clicks and hence able to action accordingly.